# How do I end this thread?

Tags: java

I am working in Eclipse Java and I made the following method to play music from a folder called 'music'...

```
public static void effect(String fileName, boolean loop) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread effect = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Mixer.Info[] mixInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
                mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixInfos[0]);

                DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
                try {
                    clip = (Clip) mixer.getLine(dataInfo);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
                    lue.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    URL soundURL = Main.class.getResource("/music/" + fileName + ".wav");
                    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);
                    clip.open(audioStream);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
                    lue.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
                    uafe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                clip.start();
                do {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } while (clip.isActive());
                if (clip.isActive() == false && loop == true) {
                    play(fileName, loop);
                }
            }
        };
        effect.start();
        effect.join();
    }
```

How would I be able to run a variable through this method that I could change to stop the music? For exammple I would change playing = false and any music that would play would stop. Any help is apprecitaed, thank you.

Comment: What's `clip`? if it has a `.start()` method, I guess it might have a `.pause()` or at least `.stop()` method.

Comment: Nevermind, [found it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html). From its `stop` method : "Stops the line. A stopped line should cease I/O activity. If the line is open and running, however, *it should retain the resources required to resume activity.*" (emphasis mine). So I guess it could be what you need.

Comment: BTW you can remove that thread and just run the code inline. The effect will be the same.

Comment: Also I guess the `if (active & loop) { play(filename, loop) }` by the end is a recursive call that ends up calling the same method again? That exposes you to stackoverflows, you should use an iterative approach if you can

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for an extra variable, just call `clip.stop()` when you want to suspend the music then `clip.start()` to resume it where it stopped.

From [`DataLine.stop()`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/DataLine.html#stop()) :

> Stops the line. A stopped line should cease I/O activity. If the line is open and running, however, it should retain the resources required to resume activity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it like a `void`, do this:

```
public static Thread effect(String fileName, boolean loop) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread effect = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Mixer.Info[] mixInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
                mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixInfos[0]);

                DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
                try {
                    clip = (Clip) mixer.getLine(dataInfo);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
                    lue.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    URL soundURL = Main.class.getResource("/music/" + fileName + ".wav");
                    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundURL);
                    clip.open(audioStream);
                } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
                    lue.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
                    uafe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
                clip.start();
                do {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                    }
                } while (clip.isActive());
                if (clip.isActive() == false && loop == true) {
                    play(fileName, loop);
                }
            }
        };
        effect.start();
        effect.join();

        return effect;
    }
```

And whenever you want to stop it, you only have to do this:

```
//Declare and start working the thread
Thread thread = effect(params...);
//Whenever you want stop it
thread.interrupt();
```